# How to aggregrate without using `GROUP BY`?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have query like the following

```
SELECT a.*, b.*

(SELECT ATTR1, ATTR2, sum(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_QTY,
ATTR3 FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ATTR4 > 0
GROUP BY ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3) a,

TABLE_B b

WHERE a.ATTR1 = b.ATTR1
AND a.ATTR2 = b.ATTR2
```

I need to `GROUP BY` only `ATTR1` to calculate the correct `TOTAL_QTY`, but the only reason I am grouping other attributes because Oracle requires that if `GROUP BY` clause is present then all `SELECT` attributes should be in the `GROUP BY` clause too.

This means every time I need an attribute in this query from Table_A then I need to put it in `GROUP BY` too. That not only looks ugly, but can have performance impact and maybe unforseen side-effect.

How do I rewrite the above query to calculate the `TOTAL_QTY` in each `ATTR1` groups, without the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: That's the nature of aggregates, you must group by otherwise the system does not know what you want to total or how to form the rows.  The only way to eliminate this effect would be to use an aggregate on the other columns max(attr1), max(attr2), however you will quickly see why group by is a better option if attr1 and attr2 have different values in different rows for the same column

Comment: "Oracle requires that if GROUP BY clause is present then all SELECT attributes should be in the GROUP BY clause too." Not true - they can also be aggregated; if the other values will always be constant for a given value of the desired grouping item, you can use a function such as MAX.

Comment: What you are looking for is ill-defined.  Say you have two rows with the same value for `attr1` and different values for `attr2`.  What do you want the result set to look like in this case?

Comment: @DaveCosta In this case any one of them is fine. Actually in my case if `attr1` is a FK to some other table. If it is present multiple times then they all point to basically one row in another table. Table_a records individual quantity values for each instance. I am simply trying to get the aggregate and some other common info from Table_a.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Oracle analytic functions. Change the inline view for `table_a` to something like:

```
select attr1,
       attr2,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by attr1 order by attr1) as total_qty,
       attr3
from   table_a
where  attr4 > 0
```

This may need tweaking a bit, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: How far backwards compatible are windowed aggregate functions?  11g only?  10g?

Comment: +1 This technique for "inline aggregates" also applies to PostgreSQL and SQL Server 2005+

Comment: This looks promising. Never knew of this, but here the issue is that I will get all the rows from a group. I need one row per group as `GROUP BY` does.

Comment: This technique assumes that the user wants a row for every record in table_a, instead of a row for every distinct value of attr1.

Comment: -1 Analytic functions should not be used as a replacement for aggregate functions.

Comment: @AppleGrew: so, if you want 1 row per distinct value of `attr1`, but you want `attr2` included in the result set, what do you want to happen if there are 2 rows for `attr1` with different values for `attr2`?

Comment: @DaveCosta This will hear weird but our data design is not stellar. In this case any value of `attr2` will be fine for me. Using that I will locate a row in another table (say C), from there I will need to locate another row in another table (say D). In this case all Cs in same group will point to same row in D. Yeah this is quite messy but I have my reasons.

Comment: Why @RobvanWijk? One more reason I don't want to use `group by` way since I may be forced to put some attributes in `group by` clause which do not have any associated indices. I fear that this can have quite a performance impact.

Comment: @Xophmeister I guess, to your query, I will need to add `ROW_NUMBER()` and choose only rows with row number `1`.

Comment: You could use this solution and, as you say, add some method for arbitrarily picking one row per value of `ATTR1`.  But I think Rob is saying that, if what you want is aggregation, it's best to express that with a `GROUP BY`.  And in this case there are ways to arbitrarily select a value of `ATTR2` without using analytics (see my answer).  I think it would be likely that the analytic approach would perform less well, although that would have to be verified by testing.

Comment: @AppleGrew: Yes, indeed. However, what Dave Costa and Rob van Wijk should be taken into account.

Comment: @AppleGrew: because your statement will (only very slightly) perform less and most important: the statement will look way more complex than needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
from (SELECT ATTR1, 
             max(ATTR2) ATTR2, 
             sum(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_QTY,
             max(ATTR3) ATTR3 
      FROM TABLE_A
      WHERE ATTR4 > 0
      GROUP BY ATTR1) a,
      TABLE_B b
WHERE a.ATTR1 = b.ATTR1
AND a.ATTR2 = b.ATTR2
```

(Assumes that for each given value of ATTR1, the values of ATTR2 and ATTR3 are constant - ie. they are functionally dependant on it.)

Comment: @AppleGrew: That answer appears to contradict your answer to Dave Costa's comment on your question. Which is it?

Comment: That comment was only for `attr1`. Other attributes could be distinct or may not be.

Comment: @AppleGrew: You need to re-read Dave Costa's comment - he said, "Say you have two rows with the same value for attr1 and **different values for attr2**. What do you want the result set to look like in this case?" To which you replied, "In this case any one of them is fine".

Comment: Sorry @Mark. I think I am overworked or something... I still don't get your point. Anyway thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: @AppleGrew: Your initial comment on this answer was "Attr2, attr3, etc. may not be unique." Both Dave and I then asked what you wanted to do if this was the case. Your initial reply sounded as though attr2 etc would be unique, but subsequent replies have indicated that it doesn't matter which values of attr2, attr3 are returned for a given value of attr1, because they will all point to the same row in D. **tl;dr** Have you tried this answer against your requirements?

Comment: I haven't tried it but this should work fine. Only concern here is, will this have bad impact if `attr2`, `attr3` are not indexed?

Comment: In my tests.. analytical version performed better than 'max' version. Many times the analytical version performed 2x or 3x times faster.

Comment: I'd like to see those performance tests, because it seems hardly possible.

Comment: At the very least, the query plans for both verions should be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

From your responses to my comments above, it sounds like you want one group per value of `ATTR1`, and you simply want any value of `ATTR2` that belongs in that group.  You can do this simply by applying a `MAX` or `MIN` to `ATTR2` in your group query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
(SELECT ATTR1, max(ATTR2) attr2, sum(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_QTY,
ATTR3 FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ATTR4 > 0
GROUP BY ATTR1, ATTR2, ATTR3) a,
TABLE_B b
WHERE a.ATTR1 = b.ATTR1
AND a.ATTR2 = b.ATTR2
```

This way you'll be arbitrarily picking a single value for `ATTR2` from all those present in the group.