# How to add XML data type in a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm creating a forum, so I have created a table with posts. One of the fields is a `Body` with of the type `XML`. Now I would like to create a query that returns all the posts and the number of children of every post. I'm doing this with an aggregate function. I need to use a group by when I'm using aggregate function. When I use the field in the `group by`, I'll get the following exception:

> The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the
>   IS NULL operator.

How can I solve this?

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    Post.PostId, Post.[Body], Count(Children.PostId)
FROM  
    dbo.Post Post, 
    dbo.Post Children 
WHERE
    Children.ParentId = Post.PostId
GROUP BY
    Post.PostId, 
    Post.[Body]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the aggregation in a CTE then join onto that

```
WITH Children(Cnt, ParentId)
     AS (SELECT COUNT(*),
                ParentId
         FROM   dbo.Post
         GROUP  BY ParentId)
SELECT P.PostId,
       P.[Body],
       ISNULL(Cnt, 0) AS Cnt
FROM   dbo.Post P
       LEFT JOIN Children /*To include childless posts*/
         ON Children.ParentId = P.PostId
ORDER  BY P.PostId
```

Comment: Would this not truncate the XML if it's longer than 8000 bytes?  Or is that now not an issue in newer SQL Server Editions?

Comment: I've added the query. Performance is very important, so I'm not sure if casting is the right way.

Comment: @MattFellows - No `varchar(max)` allows up to 2GB, same as XML though actually I probably should have said `nvarchar(max)` instead but anyway posted a better suggestion now we have seen the query.

Comment: I'm getting error 'Column 'dbo.Post.ParentId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' When I add the `order by ParentId`, I'll get 'The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.'

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - Yep. I missed the `GROUP BY`, added now. Don't add `ORDER BY` to the CTE it makes no sense. If you want an order by that needs to go on the end of the query. `ORDER BY Post.PostId`

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - Common Table Expression. It is similar to a derived table or view.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: see [MSDN docs on Using Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) - those were added in SQL Server 2005 and are extremely powerful for certain scenarios (like this one)

Comment: @MartinSmith I needed to use a `LEFT JOIN`, because not all Posts have parents (aka the thread). Maybe good to change the answer to: `;WITH Reaction(Cnt, ParentId) AS 
(
 SELECT COUNT(*), ParentId
 FROM   dbo.Post
 GROUP  BY ParentId
)
     
SELECT ISNULL(Cnt, 0), Post.*
FROM   dbo.Post Post
       LEFT JOIN Reaction
         ON Reaction.ParentId = Post.PostId 
         
        `

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - Done (I hadn't mentioned the need to include `ISNULL`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the Group by without selecting out the XML field, in a subquery, then select out the XML field, and the other collumns joining on your subquery?

Using your query you'd get:
e.g.

```
SELECT Post.[Body], sq.* FROM 
(
    SELECT Post.PostId, Count(Children.PostId)
    FROM  
      dbo.Post Post, 
      dbo.Post Children 
    WHERE
      Children.ParentId = Post.PostId
    GROUP BY
      Post.PostId
) as sq
INNER JOIN Post on Post.PostId= sq.PostId
```

However you are using a cross join / ansi join here, which is not the best way to do it.  A better way would be:

```
SELECT Post.[Body], sq.* FROM 
(
    SELECT Post.PostId, Count(Children.PostId)
    FROM  
      dbo.Post Post LEFT OUTER JOIN Children on Children.ParentId = Post.PostId
    GROUP BY
      Post.PostId
) as sq
INNER JOIN Post on Post.PostId= sq.PostId
```

Comment: I've added the query. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Answer updated - along with Cross Join / ANSI join recomendation

Comment: This queries the `Post` table twice. Only once is needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this way hope it will help you

```
SELECT  Post.PostId, Post.[Body], Count(Children.PostId) over() as totalids
    FROM  
        dbo.Post Post, 
        dbo.Post Children 
    WHERE
        Children.ParentId = Post.PostId
```

as i have worked  check this

```
 create table  xmltable  (attr1 int identity ,attr2 varchar(50),attr3  xml)

    insert into xmltable select 'i',(SELECT ( SELECT 'sometext' FOR XML PATH('body'),TYPE)FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('SampleXML')) 
    union all
     select 'j',(SELECT ( SELECT 'sometext' FOR XML PATH('body'),TYPE)FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('SampleXML'))
     union all
     select 'k',(SELECT ( SELECT 'sometext' FOR XML PATH('body'),TYPE)FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('SampleXML'))
    union all
    select 'l',(SELECT ( SELECT 'sometext' FOR XML PATH('body'),TYPE)FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('SampleXML'))


create table  xmlid  (x int ,y varchar(50))
  insert into xmlid select  1,'x'
    union all
     select 1,'y'
    union all
     select 2,'z'
    union all
     select 2,'xyz1'
     union all
     select 3,'xyz2'
    union all
     select 1,'xyz3'
     select * from  xmltable
    select * from  xmlid
```

create tables then

```
select * from  xmltable
 select * from  xmlid
 select  attr1,attr2, attr3,count(attr1) over(partition by attr2 ) as total_qtyover from  xmltable a,xmlid b
    where  a.attr1=b.x
```

also see this [How to aggregrate without using `GROUP BY`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615881/how-to-aggregrate-without-using-group-by)

Comment: Seems like flying from Amsterdam to Paris by flying over Yokohama... looks like this will produce a lot of overhead.

Comment: Ah, new code. This one doesn't work. The all `Totalids` are `1`.

Comment: @KeesC Bakker  make a try now.

Comment: Wooow... seems to be even faster than the CTE... 47% ('over') vs 53% (CTE).

Comment: @KeesC Bakker i am not geting  count of matched PostId  as per  you query? ie  Children.ParentId = Post.PostId  .

Comment: Your query: http://screencast.com/t/0zoVCt5a. CTE query: http://screencast.com/t/8uxhQLeAdX5

Answer (score 0):

I'd break it down into two queries, one to get the IDs and child counts, and a separate one to get the bodies.  Doing a `GROUP BY` requires the server to sort on the grouping fields, so you're potentially moving and comparing a lot of data when you don't need to (unless you have multiple post bodies with the same ID).

Comment: Can you provide an example based on the given query?

Comment: The query is the same, just remove the references to the post body.  Then, when you need the body, just do a separate `SELECT` using the ID of the post you want.  If you're paging the results, then you can do a `SELECT Post.[Body] FROM dbo.Post WHERE PostId IN (post-id-list)` where `post-id-list` is the list of post IDs on the current page.