# How to create a recursive counter with a Common Table Expression (CTE)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm building a forum. Now I would like to create a query that returns the number of reactions on each post. A reaction is defined as all the posts under a certain post. I would like to use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to achieve this.

So fare I've got this:

```
;WITH Reaction(Cnt, ParentId) AS 
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*), ParentId
    FROM   dbo.Post
    GROUP  BY ParentId
)

SELECT ISNULL(Cnt, 0), Post.*
FROM   dbo.Post Post
       LEFT JOIN Reaction
         ON Reaction.ParentId = Post.PostId
```

This is listing all the 'direct' posts. Now I've got to make this query count the entire tree, but I'm stuck. I've been reading a bit on CTE and I know you can make recursive queries, but I don't know how to solve the problem of creating a recursive query that counts.

Comment: Can you add the code (recursive) you've tried so far please? The MSDN CTE docs are quite useful for recursive CTEs so it'd be more useful to help you understand where you're going wrong rather than just writing the code you you

Comment: Other exceptions I've encountered were: "Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'Reaction'." and "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Build the post list first
- Aggregate later
- Don't need LEFT JOIN in the recursive clause
- Need to get ParentID in the recursive clause for the next level, otherwise you just loop PostId to PostID at the same level

Something like this:

```
;WITH Reaction AS 
(
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT P.ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post P JOIN Reaction R ON R.ParentId = P.PostId
)
SELECT COUNT(*), ParentId FROM Reaction GROUP BY ParentId;
```

Edit, updated with in-line count

```
;WITH Reaction AS
(
   SELECT ParentId FROM dbo.Post 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT P.ParentId FROM dbo.Post P JOIN Reaction R ON R.ParentId = P.PostId
)
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Reactions.ParentId) AS Cnt,
     * 
FROM Post LEFT JOIN Reaction ON Reaction.ParentId = Post.PostId
```

Comment: I would like to list post.* with the number of reactions as an added field. One of my fields is an XML field (body) that's why I was using the CTE in the first place (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616319/how-to-add-xml-data-type-in-a-group-by-clause). Hm... maybe I'll need to create two CTE's in my case.

Comment: If I do: `;WITH Reaction AS 
(
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Reaction.ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post JOIN Reaction ON Reaction.ParentId = Post.PostId
), Reactions AS
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) as Cnt, ParentId FROM Reaction GROUP BY ParentId
)

SELECT ISNULL(Cnt, 0), Post.*
FROM   dbo.Post Post
       LEFT JOIN Reactions
         ON Reactions.ParentId = Post.PostId 
         `, I get a 'The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.' exception.

Comment: Updated recursive part based on your incorrect assumption that it is Reaction.ParentId. **This** question is about recursion and counts: you wouldn't typically mix "getting data" and *counting all* in the same query

Comment: I want to use this query as a view. The app business layer will map the fields. I always need these totals, so it would make sense to include them instead of requesting the through a separate query. (I've added `GROUP BY ParentId` to your example)

Comment: Hm... a double CTE seems to work: `;WITH Reaction AS 
(
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT P.ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post P JOIN Reaction R ON R.ParentId = P.PostId
), 
Reactions AS
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT, ParentId 
 FROM Reaction 
 GROUP BY ParentId
)

SELECT ISNULL(Reactions.CNT, 0), * FROM Post LEFT JOIN Reactions ON Reactions.ParentId = Post.PostId`

Comment: OK, see what you want. I've offered an updated example with an in-line count

Comment: The count results of the latest query are not correct though :( and I have multiple selects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a double CTE to achieve counting (based on the answer of @gbn). I needed this because I had an [XML field that needed to be listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616319/how-to-add-xml-data-type-in-a-group-by-clause) so I couldn't use a `GROUP BY`.

```
;WITH Reaction AS 
(
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post
    WHERE ParentId IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT P.ParentId
    FROM dbo.Post P JOIN Reaction R ON R.ParentId = P.PostId
    WHERE P.ParentId IS NOT NULL
), 
Reactions AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT, ParentId 
    FROM Reaction 
    GROUP BY ParentId
)

SELECT ISNULL(Reactions.CNT, 0), * 
FROM Post LEFT JOIN Reactions 
    ON Reactions.ParentId = Post.PostId
```